# what would be the output?

Tags: java, inheritance

Please explain me below situation
What would be the output?

```
interface A{}
class B implements A{}
class C extends B{}
class D extends C{}
class E extends D{
public static void main(String args[]){
C c = new C();
B b = c;
A a = (E)c;
a = (B)c;
c = (C)(B)c;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being completely strict, that' won't compile because in line 4 you type `Class` instead of `class`

```
Class D extends C{}
```

And later you define twice `a` and `c`

```
C c = new C(); // once
B b = c;
A a = (E)c;    // once a
A a = (B)c;    // twice c
C c = (C)(B)c; // twice
```

Now assuming those were typos the output would be `ClassCastException` because `c` can't be *casted* to `E`.

When you perform a cast is like you were saying: *"I'm the programmer and I know this is a..."* `____(put your class here)`  And the compiler will allow you compile.

But if in **runtime** the instance is not really a ____ ( an `E` in this case,  which is not ) then it will throw `ClassCastException`.

The program won't fail with `A a = ( B ) c`; because `c` is an instance of `C` which is a subclass of `B`.

You can say that, `C` **is** a `B`. To understand it better think on the following declaration:

```
class Employee extends Object {
}
```

Every  `Employee` **is an** `Object` so the cast will succeed, actually is it so clear that it will succeed that you don't even need to put the cast operator `()`.

```
 Employee e = new Employee();
 Object o = ( Object ) e; // or much better:
 Object o2 = e; // no cast needed when assigning to superclass.
```

But not necessarily an `Object` is an `Employee`.

```
 Object o = ....
 Employee e = ( Employee ) o; // will fail if o was not created as an Employee.
```

That's why `A a = ( E ) c;`   fail, because,  the reference `c` was **not** created as an `E`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

ClassCastException at A a = (E)c;

Comment: even if the container "a" is of type "A", the cast is executed, but it is illegal since "c" contains an object of type C: since E is a specialization of C, c cannot be cast to E.

Comment: Because the type of the object 'c' is C. It can't be cast to E.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually trying it, I'll go out on a limb and say that this line will cause two compiler errors:

```
C c = (C)(B)c;
```

1. You're declaring the variable 'c' twice.
2. You can't cast from B to C.

And if you actually put a double cast like that into a real project, then you deserve to get your ass kicked.

Comment: OK, I see that you've edited the code so that 1 doesn't apply anymore. And I was also wrong about 2.

Comment: I have already corrected the mistake of declaring variable c twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The object c is created as a new C.  Since C extends B it is no problem assigning it to a variable of type B.  However C knows nothing about E, so you can't cast here.  You can only do this with super-classes.  Since A is the absolute top level it is fine to assign any objects of the types you have defined to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no output. Because you didn't tell it where the entry point is.

If you *did* specify the main class as <strike>D</strike> E, there would still be no output since all those classes extend an empty class.